# What is $\sigma\{X_j ; j=0,...n\}$ where $X_j$ are independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

What is $F_n = \sigma\{X_j ; j=0,...n\}$ where $X_j$ are independent $L^1(\Omega,F,P)$.

Am I correct in saying that an event $A$ in the sigma algebra $F_n$ is like: $\{w\epsilon\Omega; X_j\epsilon A_j\}$. {So every A in $F_n$ is a unique choice of $X_j$ takes on for $j\epsilon\{0,...n\}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sigma(X_0,X_1,...,X_n)=\{(X_0,X_1,...,X_n)^{-1}(A): A \text  { is Borel in } \mathbb R^{n+1}\}$$ $$=\{\omega: (X_0(\omega),X_1(\omega),...,X_n(\omega)) \in A: A \text { is Borel in }  \mathbb R^{n+1}\}.$$

Comment: So every event in that sigma algebra is composed of n+1 dimensional singletons.

Comment: Since sigma algebras need not be closed under uncountable unions it is wrong to think of a Borel set as 'composed' of singletons. Your description works only when you are dealing with discrete random variables.

Comment: How is this different to the cartesian product of $\sigma(X_1)...\sigma(X_n)$

Comment: It is not different. The cartesian product coincides with $\sigma(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$.